# How to create table with geometry column in GPKG with spatialite?

Tags: spatialite, geopackage

I want to create a vectorial GPKG with spatialite.

With the help of the documenation (here: http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.3.0.html#p16gpkg ), I've created a `sql` script that look like this:

```sql
SELECT EnableGpkgMode();
SELECT gpkgCreateBaseTables();

CREATE TABLE grid ('fid' INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT);
SELECT gpkgAddGeometryColumn('grid', 'geom', 'GEOMETRY', 0, 0, 4326);
```

Here is my output:

```
$ rm -f test.gpkg && spatialite test.gpkg < test.sql
SpatiaLite version ..: 4.3.0a   Supported Extensions:
    - 'VirtualShape'    [direct Shapefile access]
    - 'VirtualDbf'      [direct DBF access]
    - 'VirtualXL'       [direct XLS access]
    - 'VirtualText'     [direct CSV/TXT access]
    - 'VirtualNetwork'  [Dijkstra shortest path]
    - 'RTree'       [Spatial Index - R*Tree]
    - 'MbrCache'        [Spatial Index - MBR cache]
    - 'VirtualSpatialIndex' [R*Tree metahandler]
    - 'VirtualElementary'   [ElemGeoms metahandler]
    - 'VirtualXPath'    [XML Path Language - XPath]
    - 'VirtualFDO'      [FDO-OGR interoperability]
    - 'VirtualGPKG' [OGC GeoPackage interoperability]
    - 'VirtualBBox'     [BoundingBox tables]
    - 'SpatiaLite'      [Spatial SQL - OGC]
PROJ.4 version ......: Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018
GEOS version ........: 3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771
TARGET CPU ..........: x86_64-linux-gnu
the SPATIAL_REF_SYS table already contains some row(s)


Error: near line 5: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

What did I do wrong ?

---

Answered here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321596/how-to-create-table-with-geometry-column-in-gpkg-with-spatialite